# check if object is null but still get error

Tags: excel, object, range, vba

Hi I have a valid Range object but I am getting object required error

```
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
   row = rng.row
   col = rng.Column
End If
```

it get into if but get error at (Set row = rng.row) line

whole code is this:

```
Dim str() As String
str = GetArray(ActiveSheet.Range("A3"))
Dim element As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("D3")
For Each element In str
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
     element, _
     Destination:=rng)
    .Name = "technicals_1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Range(Cells(rng.row, rng.Column), Cells(rng.row + 70, rng.Column + 1)).Select
Selection.Copy
rng.Offset(0, 2).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, transpose:=True
Range(Cells(rng.row, rng.Column), Cells(rng.row + 70, rng.Column + 1)).Select
Selection.QueryTable.Delete
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
/* AFTER THIS LINE I GET OBJECT REQUIRED ERROR */
Range(Cells(rng.row, rng.Column), Cells(rng.row, rng.Column + 70)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
Next element

End Sub
```

I have edited it please read it again
please read the part that I typed this comment:

/* AFTER THIS LINE I GET OBJECT REQUIRED ERROR */

what should I do?
Thanks

Comment: You've just deleted the range, so you can't refer to it. You know it's D3 so use that row/column number.

Comment: so what should I do to avoid that

Comment: At least 3 people did but your responses were rude so we all gave up. With 8,000,000 questions, stack overflow is an answerer's market.

Comment: please give another chance... I want to delete range but I need its Coordinates

Comment: solved by using Selection.Cells(1,1) instead of rng.row & rng.column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you delete the range you must redefine it.

It is better to not use a range variable, but to use the cells property with the coordinates of cell D3 (i.e. Cells(3,4)).

So, to fix your problem either insert

```
Set rng = Range("D3")
```

before the line that's giving the error and again after the next Range(...).Delete statement or don't use the range variable (since you're just using the row and column properties of the object) and replace rng.Column and rng.Row with variables defined as the correct row and column numbers.